# Python List Values being assigned to each other

Tags: python

I'm having a problem writing the following code:

```
D = [
        [0,3,8,999,-4],
        [999,0,999,1,7],
        [999,4,0,999,999],
        [2,999,-5,0,999],
        [999,999,999,6,0]
    ]

def FloydWarshall (W):
    matrices = [W[:]]
    pred = [W[:]]

    print (matrices is pred)
    print (pred is matrices)
    print (pred is W)
    print (matrices is W)

    for i in range(0,len(pred[0])):
        for j in range(len(pred[0][i])):

            if pred[0][i][j] != 999 and pred[0][i][j] != 0:
                pred[0][i][j] = i +1
            else:
                pred[0][i][j] = False 

    return (matrices,pred)
FloydWarshall(D)
```

the values that are being returned are the exact same matrices, why is this? The print statement say that they are not pointers to the same spot in memory, correct?

Comment: The `is` keyword checks the `id`'s of the two variables. The id's corresponds to the emplacements of the variables in memory (in CPython implementation). As said in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: @segfolt: That's what OP wanted. `a is b` is `True` if they're the same object.

Comment: @Blender: Yes. That was just a precision because of the OP's last question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only making a shallow copy of the nested lists, so mutating them will still affect both matrices. You might want to use `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: Correct you are. Thank you!